# Seam 2.2 App on JBoss 7.1?

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, ejb, seam

We have deployed our JBoss Seam 2.2 application on JBoss 5.1 with PostgreSQL as the database.  It makes use of EJBs, JPA (Hibernate), JSF (Richfaces and Primefaces), Servlets, and JMS queues and topics.  Recently, we've decided to migrate the platform to JBoss 7.1 to take advantage of its lower overhead, as well as to keep in step with changes in technology.

Is it possible to run Seam 2.2 applications on JBoss 7.1?  I realize the Hibernate/JPA version is different, and I'm assuming the JSF version is as well.  Are there ways to compensate for this?  What changes to our code and configuration could I potentially have to make in order to run it on this platform?

Comment: Not really an answer but I just want to prepare you that this can quickly become extraordinarily complex.  I spent weeks basically removing the bundled JSF 1.2 implementation from JBoss 5 just so that I could run a JSF 2.0 application from it.  Keep in mind that by doing this I broke the management console which was built on JSF 1.2.

Comment: I recommend you to do a quick trial with JBoss 6.1 which is technically closer to JBoss 5 than JBoss 7. You may face less troubles and get time to migrate your application to JBoss Seam 3 targetting JBoss 7.1 or newer. I really expect JBoss team to propose a migration path from Seam 2.2 to Seam 3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is yes you can migrate your Seam 2.2 app to JBoss AS 7.

The main challenge is going to be classloading because of how class loading is completely re-architected with AS 7.

Instead of me going through all the steps here I simply want to point you to the official documentation of how this was done on one of the sample apps (Seam Booking application). It provides a step-by-step guide on how you can migrate a Seam 2.x app to JBoss AS 7 and also points some of the issues you will face and how you can handle them.

The guide is located [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Seam+2+Booking+EAR+Migration+of+Binaries+-+Step+by+Step).

Other useful references

1. [JBoss AS 7 Classloading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Class+Loading+in+AS7)
2. [Seam 2 JPA Example](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/15/seam-2-jpa-example-on-jboss-as7)

Good luck!