# JBoss 7.1 and Seam 2.2 -- Caching?

Tags: caching, jboss, seam, jboss7.x

I have configured a JBoss Seam 2.2 application to run on JBoss 7.1.  (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833537/error-deploying-seam-2-2-app-on-jboss-7-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674253/seam-2-2-app-on-jboss-7-1)) It runs with no problem after using [this guide](https://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/07/15/seam-2-jpa-example-on-jboss-as7) as a reference.  However, every reference document that I've read either talks about disabling caching or ignores it altogether.  I know that JBoss 7 has a new caching mechanism from previous versions.  What do I need to do to leverage this within my Seam app?  Or, do I just include the JARs from the previous caching implementation and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Seam 2 as you probably realized has been morphed into [CDI](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=299) and most of the integration going forward will be around CDI.

Having said that there are ways to leverage infinispan (the new Cache used within JBoss AS 7) in your Seam application.

Here are a few references that might help you

1. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/infinispan/infinispan-tutorial-part-1
2. http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/infinispan/infinispan-tutorial-part-2
3. http://infinispan.blogspot.com/2011/09/when-infinispan-meets-cdi.html

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: That doesn't help at all with Seam 2, though.  Is Infinispan supported by Seam 2.2 applications?

Comment: Infinispan is a general purpose Data Grid. You can use the simple API's to create instances of cache. It doesn't matter whether you are using Seam 2 or a standalone Java App. If you asking about tighter intergation like with Seam 3, then what I described above is still valid.

Comment: My question is about Seam 2.2 integration.  Seam has built in caching support that uses various backend cache providers.  Hence, the ability to use JSF tags like <s:cache />.  Is Infinispan supported as one of these providers?  I realize it's available for Seam 3, but that's not the version I'm on.